# Is it possible to style the entire Application without using a single "style" attribute?

Tags: android

My question may be stupid but is it possible to style the entire Application via themes.xml without using a single style attribute in the layouts?

E.g. I've this imageView and set the style via app:style:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
android:src="@drawable/ic_bottom_sheet_edit" 
app:style="@style/imageViewStyle"/>
```

Is it possible to set the style like?:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
<item name="imageViewStyle">@style/MyTheme.ImageView</item>
```

Can this be done for all Components and how can I figure out the correct item names (in the case above: imageViewStyle) that I've to set? I know that this is possible for at least TabLayout and the Toolbar but how about other components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for all.  At app level themes you can set attributes like

```
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
```

In case you want style for specific view which is not possible via app theme, you can go for custom views.

```
class AppImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {

 init{
  //inflate layout here with desired style
  //also good practice to have custom attribute set in values/attrs.xml     

  }
}
```

and finally you can use this view in layouts as you would use android default views.

```
<AppImageView>
 width
height
..
</AppImageView>
```